# Installing lilypond on Big Sur

Tags: software, lilypond

Has anyone here installed lilypond on Big Sur (Mac)? The .dmg file and `brew install --cask lilypond` both informed me that the distributed version of lilypond only work with macOS versions up to Mojave...

Comment: That would imply parts of it are still 32-bit. Mojave was the last OS to support any 32-bit at all. Did you look at the lilypond page? https://lilypond.org/macos-x.html

Comment: Yes, though I didn't see anything regarding Mac 11.x, which is what I'm on. But I also didn't see anything about brew and there was a cask, so I thought perhaps there was a distribution not specified on the lilypond page that would be compatible with Big Sur...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have found that for Lilypond, [MacPorts](https://www.macports.org/) is the *only* reliable way to get a new version on newer macOS builds.

I have my MacPorts install working happily alongside my homebrew install, with default settings for both.

Once you get MacPorts installed, lilypond is as simple as

```
sudo port install lilypond
```

If you have any trouble installing it, i.e. a conflict with a brew package, you can use trace mode to install it using *only* MacPorts files:

```
sudo port -t install lilypond
```

Comment: One thing to note: if you have a TeX install already, i.e. from homebrew or MacTeX, you can use the `mactex` variant, via `sudo port install lilypond +mactex`. You may have to configure some things, see the lilypond notes via `port notes lilypond`

This will usually speed up the install a bit, because Lily needs tex for installation, but not runtime.

Comment: Does anyone know why Lilypond is so badly supported on macOS?? (Since I already use Homebrew for lots of stuff, I've been using a Lilypond cask — but that only works up to 10.14 Mojave. And I quail at the idea of installing _another_ entire package manager, and 23 support packages — probably with shedloads of further dependencies — simply for this one application.)

Comment: I believe its because there is some (perceived) licensing issue between an Apple provided library and a GNU one, which lilypond is licensed under. MacPorts "works" because it compiles it.

It would, of course, be possible to get a Homebrew tap working that compiled Lilypond, and use it, but I haven't found one that does it yet.

As for the leaf dependencies with MacPorts, its pretty easy to reclaim most of them, my Ly install isn't too space hungry

Comment: Dunno if this is a coincidence, but I've just updated Homebrew, and find there's now a straight Lilypond formula, with a 64-bit executable! \o/ No GUI; just the command-line version — but that's all I use anyway. A web search finds [this 22-hour-old announcement](https://www.mail-archive.com/lilypond-user@gnu.org/msg146249.html). Apparently it uses Guile 2 (not 1.8 like other versions of Lilypond) so may have teething problems — but it just rendered 3 pages of mine just about identically, so first impressions are great!